# Highcharts: multiple charts, click on one chart to produce a new series that appears on others

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I am working on a complex issue.  I have multiple charts in multiple containers.  The data is made up of a variety of x-y pairs from a larger data set that has a common sample ID.  What I want to do is take one chart in container 1 and be able to select some of the points on the chart.  These selected points will become a new series of "highlighted" points that will essentially cover the original points.  Then, I want to get the IDs for these selected points and have it create the "same" series in the other charts based on the IDs.  So, as I select the points in one chart, the other charts update with the same points.

I've seen examples from here: [If a point is clicked then add a marker in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569611/if-a-point-is-clicked-then-add-a-marker-in-highcharts) that adds a marker, so I have some good leads, but before I go forward and try this, I want to be sure this can be done.

I'm not asking for people to do all the work for me, but does anyone know if it's possible to do what I want to do?  Once I get an answer on that, I'll work on the code.  I just don't want to start work on something just to find out it's an impossibility.

Thanks!

Comment: Take look at the http://jsfiddle.net/bSdNU/ and use getselectedpints which allows to get points, then you can create new chart or add new series by addSeries function.

Comment: When I load the fiddle the alert doesn't come up when I click on it.  In the console it says selectedPoints is not defined. is it working correctly?

Comment: Please update my code with yours and we will check